# Cochain complex originated from projective resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra

Following is my simple curiosity :

Consider a **projective resolution** which is an exact $G$-module and $G=\{1\}$

$$(\ast) \cdots \rightarrow P_n \cdots P_0\rightarrow {\bf Z} \rightarrow 0$$

Hence we have chain complex : Let $C^i = {\rm Hom}_{{\bf Z}G} (P_i, A)$ where $A={\bf Z}$ is an abelian group so that we have $$  {\rm Hom}_{{\bf Z}G} ({\bf Z}, A)={\bf Z},\  0\rightarrow {\bf Z} \rightarrow C^0 \cdots \rightarrow C^i \cdots $$

Consider the following cochain $$(\ast\ast)\  0\rightarrow {\bf Z} \rightarrow_{\times 8} {\bf Z}=C^0  \rightarrow {\bf Z}_4=C^1\rightarrow 0$$

**Question** : $\ast\ast$ can be originated from projective resolution of the form $\ast$ ?

Comment: My answer : Since $P_0={\bf Z}^n$ and $C^0={\bf Z}$ so $P_0={\bf Z}$. Hence if $P_0\rightarrow_{d_0} {\bf Z}$, $d_0(1)=1$ or $-1$. So $ {\bf Z} \rightarrow_{D_0} C^0$ has $D_0(1)=1$ or $-1$. Contradiction.